# Is it possible to restrict view to certain case activities?

Tags: wordpress, civicase, permissions, acl

We are currently evaluating CiviCRM 5.4.1 and CiviCase on Wordpress 4.9.8

One of the requirements is to limit access to certain activity types.

In simple words, some users are not allowed to view sensitive activity types.

So far I only found:

- CiviCRM: view all activities
- CiviCase: access all cases and activities
- CiviCase: access my cases and activities

But we need to restrict access to activity type: Payment

Any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you can install the [Activity Type ACL](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.activitytypeacl) extension which will give you permissions on a per-activity type basis.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works well with 5.4.1 on WP 4.9.8